# 'Query Interrupted',How to run very long MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to run MySQL procedure that adds over 20 million records for testing.

The maximum that I've reached is '980,737' before I get 'Query Interrupted'.

Every time I try very long procedures I get 'Query Interrupted', I tried

```
SET global max_execution_time = 2400000;
```

with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is MySQLWorkBench,use command line and it will work.